# A smooth non-stably trivial smooth vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, topological-k-theory

This may well be just a look-up, but do you have an example of a non-stably trivial smooth vector bundle? If it has a presentation as the vector bundle associated to the representation of some (classical) Lie group, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Möbius bundle over $S^1$ has this property.

Comment: Yes so it would appear. I have no idea why I had convinced myself that it didn't.